# Deleted .vagrant directory prevents me from SSH

Tags: vagrant

I am using Vagrant to run 4 VMs. My Vagrantfile looks like this :

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.2"
  config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/vagrant"

  # Master1
  config.vm.define :master1 do |m1|
    m1.vm.hostname = "master1.mycluster"
    m1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.12"
    m1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.memory = "8192"
    end
    m1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 50070, host: 50070
  end

  # Other machines are defined in the same way
end
```

Everything was working perfectly, until I accidentally removed the `.vagrant` folder from my project directory.

First, I tried putting back my VMs ids into `.vagrant/machines/${name}/virtualbox/id`. Running `vagrant status` did see my VMs as up and running, but I couldn't connect via SSH anymore.

I looked for a solution, but couldn't find one, so I decided to destroy and re-start my VMs. Sadly, the `vagrant up` (or `vagrant up --provision`) command got stuck trying to SSH to **127.0.0.1:2222**. Shouldn't it be trying to connect to **192.168.0.12:2222**, instead ? Here is the command output :

```
Bringing machine 'master1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> master1: Importing base box 'bento/centos-7.2'...
==> master1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> master1: Checking if box 'bento/centos-7.2' is up to date...
==> master1: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant_master1_1493974030138_66977
==> master1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> master1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    master1: Adapter 1: nat
    master1: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> master1: Forwarding ports...
    master1: 50070 (guest) => 50070 (host) (adapter 1)
    master1: 61888 (guest) => 61888 (host) (adapter 1)
    master1: 18080 (guest) => 18080 (host) (adapter 1)
    master1: 9995 (guest) => 9959 (host) (adapter 1)
    master1: 8787 (guest) => 8787 (host) (adapter 1)
    master1: 8088 (guest) => 8088 (host) (adapter 1)
    master1: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> master1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> master1: Booting VM...
==> master1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    master1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    master1: SSH username: vagrant
    master1: SSH auth method: private key
    master1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    master1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Though, I can connect to my VM by doing `ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1`, and the SSH folder does not seem to have permission issues.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ls -la /home/vagrant/.ssh/
total 4
drwx------. 2 vagrant root     28  1 déc.  15:56 .
drwx------. 3 vagrant vagrant  90  1 déc.  15:57 ..
-rw-------. 1 vagrant root    409  1 déc.  15:56 authorized_keys
```

What can I do to be able to run VMs again, using Vagrant ?

Comment: `127.0.0.1:2222` is the correct url to be used by vagrant, vagrant has not set the IP on the VM on the first time it runs the ssh connection. can you connect to the vm through virtualbox ? (vagrant/vagrant as user/password) and check the right of `/home/vagrant/.ssh` folder

Comment: you'd need vnc or something to log into your remote server and open virtual box - if you need to check the ssh right, you cannot initiate ssh connection

Comment: I have been able to connect to my VM using a simple SSH command, I edited my question to answer your questions. The rights seem to be OK.

Comment: Though, I think your question lead me to the real problem: while trying to fix the first issue, I modified the `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`. The VM `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` does contain a public key named vagrant insecure public key, but it does not correspond to the new private key. Do you know where this public key come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Don't modify `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`

While trying to fix the first issue (couldn't connect to VM after putting back the VM id in .vagrant), I found a post somewhere telling that this was an issue with the file vagrant insecure private key, located in `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`.

I tried to put a custom private key there, which is why it didn't work later using vagrant up.

The solution was to find the default Vagrant insecure private key here : https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys, and put it back in `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`.